# How to run an Android app to an device?

Tags: android, device

This show me when i run the android studio project, but in the phone the app doesn't start.

[image]

Comment: Do you find your app in the App Drawer of your phone?

Comment: What brand of phone do you have?

Comment: Do you have developer options enabled on your device, and have set the computer as a trusted debugging device on your device?

Comment: @NendoTaka, Lenovo, but not original

Comment: @JohnWhite, i select the develepor options, i d'ont set the computer as a trusted debugging device, i d'ont know how to do that

Comment: @TimoSta, no   i d'ont fiind

Comment: Have you tried following all of these directions http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: @NendoTaka, i follow first step and is work, i'm so enthusiastic, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The details you have provided is not sufficient for a proper answer.
Do check your AndroidManifest File.It may not have been properely configured
Here's an example from AndroidManifest.xml. You need to specify the MAIN and LAUNCHER in the intent filter for the activity you want to start on launch

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="ExampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem for was :
1.

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
```

and 
2.In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable= "true" to the  element.